# Function does not work when return is specified

Tags: python, return, telethon

I am trying to make a function that fetches the list of contacts of a user from telegram using the telethon library, after fetching the contacts it will extract the `user id` and the `first name` of each contact then it will compare the `first name` of the contact and the name entered by the user and if it is similar it will send a message that the user input. The function works as it sends the message successfully to the expected contact but when I use a return statement it does not work

```py
async def sendUserMessage(self, response, message):
    client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.connect()
    result = await client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(
        hash=0
    ))
    for user in result.users:
        try:
            s = SequenceMatcher(None, response, user.first_name)
            print(s.ratio())
            print(response)
            print(user.first_name)
            if s.ratio() > 0.75:
                print(response, user.id)
                receiver = InputPeerUser(user.id, 0)
                await client.send_message(receiver, message, parse_mode='html')
                return print("Sent a message successfully")
            else:
                return print("Could not send message")

        except Exception:
            pass
    await client.disconnect()

a = input("Who do you want to send the message to? ")
b = input("What do you wanna send? ")

async def main():
    await Methods().sendUserMessage(a, b)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here a is the person I want the message to be sent to and b is the message.
Any help would be appreciated

Update

I figured out the problem, Return statements break the loop before the conditions are met.

Is there any way to return a statement only once when the condition is met?

[image]

I used boolean flag but it still does not work, I am not sure if I used it the right way

```py
async def sendUserMessage(self, response, message):
    isSent = False
    client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.connect()
    result = await client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(
        hash=0
    ))
    for user in result.users:
        try:
            s = SequenceMatcher(None, response, user.first_name)
            if s.ratio() > 0.75:
                receiver = InputPeerUser(user.id, 0)
                await client.send_message(receiver, message, parse_mode='html')
                isSent = True
            else:
                isSent = False
        except Exception:
            pass
    await client.disconnect()
    if isSent:
        print("Message sent successfully")
    else:
        print("Message could not be sent")
```

Comment: try remover `asyncio` things first, just to make code simpler.

Comment: It's a coroutine so it has to be awaited, other wise it won't work

Comment: There is a total of 25 users, when I use return it only iterates through the first user and then it ends the function

Comment: sorry. i'm not familiar with the `TelegramClient` library. it is best if you write a simple fake so called *coroutine* function, to replace `TelegramClient` and let us easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am new to asyncio and coroutines, I am not really sure on how to write a fake coroutine

Comment: My doubt is why does it only loop through the first user when I use return but it loops through all 25 users when I do not use return

Comment: `return` exits the function. use `print("blah")` instead of `return print("blah")`

Comment: The problem with print is that it prints out the statement 24 times when the condition is not met and once when the condition is met

Comment: whats your expectation here ? Do u want to still go over the other contacts  after the first contact is found or not ?

Comment: I want the function to return `Message sent successfully` only once if the message is sent successfully else return `Message could not be sent` only once if the message failed to be sent

Comment: Then dont print in the loop. You should print at the end outside the loop based on whether the message was sent or not.  Instead of printing, use a boolean flag and print based on that

Comment: Could you add this as an answer

Comment: I tried to use a Boolean flag but not sure why it did not work

Comment: what exactly did not work? if your expectation is to print `Message sent successfully` if any user matches, then remove the `else: isSent = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using a `boolean flag` instead of using print in the for loop

```
async def sendUserMessage(self, response):
        isSent = False
        client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
        await client.connect()
        result = await client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(
            hash=0
        ))
        for user in result.users:
            try:
                s = SequenceMatcher(None, response, user.first_name)
                if s.ratio() > 0.75 or distance.levenshtein(response, user.first_name) < 3:
                    speak("What do you wanna send?")
                    message = takeCommand()
                    isSent = True
                    receiver = InputPeerUser(user.id, 0)
                    await client.send_message(receiver, message, parse_mode='html')
                else:
                    pass
            except Exception:
                pass
        await client.disconnect()
        if isSent:
            speak("Message sent successfully")
        else:
            speak("Could not find that user in your contacts")
```